# Alert Dialog closes unexpectedly, upon keyboard popup only

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-alertdialog

Here's a strange one I'm having.  I have a simple `RecylcerView` activity that contains a list of single `TextViews` of user defined location tags.  "Home", "Work", "New York", etc.

The user can swipe left and rename the `TextView` if desired.  Upon swiping left, an AlertDialog pops up with an `EditText` box.  My code works great for any `View` that is near the top of my page.  However, for any `View` that is lower on the page, the alert dialog closes upon the keyboard popup.  Seemingly, my code doesn't work for any `RecylcerView` that originated from a location behind the keyboard popup.  Weird.  But that's what it seems like.

I've tried switching the keyboard to (1) automatically popup and (2) only popup upon user clicking the `EditText`.  Either way it's the same, the Alert Dialog closes when the keyboard pops up for those on the lower half of the page.

I've tried setting the dialog cancelable to (false).  Doesn't matter.  Same problem.

Getting the same problem on my phone and within emulators.

Log cat shows nothing unusual, app doesn't crash, no apparent errors.

Anybody ever experienced this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution.  Not sure why it works, but it does.

In the onCreate() I added this

```
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);
```

but that alone didn't auto pop the keyboard (which is the behavior I wanted), so I needed to create a Dialog on top of my AlertBuilder to add a second layer of setSoftInputMode

```
    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE);
    dialog.show();
```